# how will I erase or to make the border invisible of the cell that I completed using table.completeRow()

Tags: java, itext, spring-mybatis

this is my code where I make an invisible border for the Merchant Column and complete the row, the Merchant column has no border, but the rest of the row had, I don't know to make it invisible.

```
PdfPCell cellMerchantTitle = rowCellStyle("Merchant", fontTitleSize);
cellMerchantTitle.setColspan(2);
table.addCell(cellSystemTitle);
table.completeRow();

public PdfPCell rowCellStyle(String cellValue, Font fontStyle){
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(cellValue, fontStyle));
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
return cell;
}
```

I already try this

```
table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
```

Comment: Where did you add `table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);`? That should work, but you need to add this *before* you complete the row.

Comment: Yes, thanks It solved my problem.

Comment: OK, I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);` should do the trick, but you have to make sure you add this line *before* completing the row:

```
table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
PdfPCell cellMerchantTitle = rowCellStyle("Merchant", fontTitleSize);
cellMerchantTitle.setColspan(2);
table.addCell(cellSystemTitle);
table.completeRow();
```